# Change in Behavior for EventTimeSessionWindows from Flink 1.11.1 to 1.14.0

Tags: apache-flink

I observed what appears to be a change in behavior for EventTimeSessionWindows when upgrading from 1.11.1 to 1.14.0. This was identified in a unit test.

For a window with a defined time gap of 10 seconds.

- Publish KEY_1 with eventtime 1 second
- Publish KEY_1 with eventtime 3 seconds
- Publish KEY_1 with eventtime 2 seconds
- Publish KEY_2 with eventtime 101 seconds

For Flink 1.11.1 the window for KEY_1 closes, reduces, and publishes, supposedly because KEY_2 had an event time greater than 10 seconds after the last message in KEY_1's window. KEY_2 window would also not close.  In the absence of KEY_2 the KEY_1 window would not close.

For Flink 1.14.0 the main difference is that the window for KEY_2 DOES close even though there are no new messages after 111 seconds.

This appears to be a change in behavior. The nearest I could find was https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20443 but that’s in 1.14.1. I also noticed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19777 which was in 1.11.3 but couldn't ascertain if that would have resulted in this behavior.  Is there an explanation for this change in behavior? Is it expected or desirable? Is it because all pending windows are automatically closed based on an updated trigger behavior?

I tested the same behavior for ProcessingTimeSessionWindows and did not observe a similar change in behavior.

Thanks.
Jai

```
@Test
public void testEventTime() throws Exception {
  StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

  // configure your test environment
  env.setParallelism(1);
  env.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(Document.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);

  // values are collected in a static variable
  CollectSink.values.clear();

  // create a stream of custom elements and apply transformations
  SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Document>> inputStream = buildStream(env, this.generateTestOrders());

  SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Document>> intermediateStream = this.documentDebounceFunction.insertIntoPipeline(inputStream);

  intermediateStream.addSink(new CollectSink());

  // execute
  env.execute();

  // verify your results
  Assertions.assertEquals(1, CollectSink.values.size());

  Map<String, Long> expectedVersions = Maps.newHashMap();
  expectedVersions.put(KEY_1, 2L);

  for (Tuple2<String, Document> actual : CollectSink.values) {
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedVersions.get(actual.f0), actual.f1.getVersion());
  }
}

// create a testing sink
private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Tuple2<String, Document>> {

  // must be static
  public static final List<Tuple2<String, Document>> values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

  @Override
  public void invoke(Tuple2<String, Document> value, SinkFunction.Context context) {
    values.add(value);
  }
}

public List<Tuple2<String, Document>> generateTestOrders() {
  List<Tuple2<String, Document>> testMessages = Lists.newArrayList();

  // KEY_1
  testMessages.add(
    Tuple2.of(
      KEY_1, 
      Document.newBuilder()
        .setVersion(1)
        .setUpdatedAt(
          Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(1).build())
        .build()));

  testMessages.add(
    Tuple2.of(
      KEY_1,
      Document.newBuilder()
        .setVersion(2)
        .setUpdatedAt(
          Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(3).build())
        .build()));

  testMessages.add(
    Tuple2.of(
      KEY_1,
      Document.newBuilder()
        .setVersion(3)
        .setUpdatedAt(
          Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(2).build())
        .build()));

  // KEY_2 -- WAY IN THE FUTURE
  testMessages.add(
    Tuple2.of(
      KEY_2,
      Document.newBuilder()
        .setVersion(15)
        .setUpdatedAt(
          Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(101).build())
        .build()));

  return ImmutableList.copyOf(testMessages);
}

private SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Document>> buildStream(
  StreamExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment,
  List<Tuple2<String, Document>> inputMessages) {
  inputMessages =
    inputMessages.stream()
      .sorted(
        Comparator.comparingInt(
          msg -> (int) ProtobufTypeConversion.toMillis(msg.f1.getUpdatedAt())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

  WatermarkStrategy<Tuple2<String, Document>> watermarkStrategy =
    WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps();

  return executionEnvironment
    .fromCollection(
      inputMessages, TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<String, Document>>() {}))
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
      watermarkStrategy.withTimestampAssigner(
        (event, timestamp) -> Timestamps.toMillis(event.f1.getUpdatedAt())));
}
```

Comment: A number of things have changed since 1.11, particularly in the direction of unifying batch and streaming, or in other words, working with bounded streams (which is what's happening in tests). It's worthwhile to read the release announcements and release notes before upgrading. But can you share the code for the unit test? I'm particularly interested in seeing which source it is using, but other things may be relevant as well.

Comment: Test added to the question.  The test fails because the actual result includes KEY_2 even though there is no subsequent messages.  And thank you for pointing us as the release notes, we had noticed there were considerable changes to bounded streams, but weren't sure this was a desired change in behavior.